# Where to put "custom conversions" with @BindingConversion in Android Data Binding and why?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

The [official documentation on custom conversions in Android Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#custom_conversions) is pretty scant. It says to create a static converter with the method signature to match the conversion, and annotate it with [@BindingConversion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingConversion.html), but it doesn't say where it will look for those methods. Does it just scan every static method in the whole app for BindingConversion annotations? Should I create a specific class for these conversions? Should it be in a specific package? Obviously it should be public. Please elaborate.

Comment: I was also confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be any class in any package. It uses the java annotation processor, so it only picks up the annotated methods.

Comment: It would be helpful if that part of the documentation is more detail :)